# Instantly monitor textarea for specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im building a form that connects to our backend helpdesk. And one of the things I am wanting to do is monitor the body text area field for a specific phrase. Lets say the phrase is "new computer". When someone types in "I want a new computer" a function will fire that creates a popup telling them they need to go to the more advanced form.

Here is what I have so far

```
$('#body').on('change', function () {
    if ($("#body").val().toLowerCase().indexOf("new computer") >= 0){
        alert("stuff");
    } else {
        //Other stuff
    }
});
```

The problem is that this method is pretty slow. It takes about 10 seconds or so after the word was typed for the alert to fire. Not the end of the world but Ive seen where it happens almost instantly. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `.keyup()` as an alternative? https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the same code using `keyup` instead of `change`

```js
$('#body').on('keyup', function () {
    if ($("#body").val().toLowerCase().indexOf("new computer") >= 0){
        alert("stuff");
    } else {
        //Other stuff
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='body'></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks! This does work but I still seem to have about a 10 second delay between when i type "new computer" and when the function actually fires.

Comment: is there other js before this that might take time? Anything special about your computer/software?

Comment: Hm, Im not linking to anything other than a self host jquery file. I am using the Skeleton HTML framework with font awesome and a google font.

Comment: Aha, I think I got it. Im running code on the "else" statement that takes a half a second to animate. Every keystroke I think its trying to animate it so it has to wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
jQuery("#body").on("keyup", function(e){
  if ($(t).val(his).toLowerCase().indexOf("new computer") >= 0){
    alert("stuff");
  } else {
    //Other stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: bind() is deprecated...it uses `on()` internally better to just use `on()` directly

Comment: Yup, you are right and i already changed it. I don't honestly know why i used bind instead of `on`, sorry about that and thanks for pointing it out @charlietfl

Comment: perhaps you've been working with angular lately..which uses bind? Not a big deal..was just pointing it out

Comment: Yeah! I have been working with angular the whole last year so, that may be the reason hah!